# responsivevoice not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, responsivevoice

I was checking this Javascript Text-to-Speech conversion API - http://responsivevoice.org/, for one of my projects.

I have created a snippet out of the fiddle to demonstrate the problem:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/responsivevoice.js"></script>

<textarea id="text" cols="45" rows="3">Hello, world!</textarea>
 
<input 
  onclick="responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(),'US English Female');" 
  type="button" 
  value="Play" 
/>
```

In Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 8.1, I am getting the following error in the console:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Audio(url)')` pointing to the `responsivevoice` library.

It works fine on Chrome and Firefox. How do I get this working in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue with safari And HTML5 Audio. install quick time and follow this link:

http://infobrink.com/safari-not-liking-the-html5-audio/

Comment: Is there an easier way? Apparently, we cant do this on client's machine.

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885616/cant-detect-if-responsivevoice-isplaying